# rails 5.1 how to render json and keep quotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

At my rails app tests controller, when I `render json: {"sum": 9}` it returns `{sum: 9}`, how can I keep the double quotes on sum? I want the result to be `{"sum": 9}`

Answer (score 1):

Although the difference is also related to the difference between using a Symbol and using a String... (see the [`JSON.parse` documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse))...

This is mostly related to the way you're reading the data (as a human) rather than how the actual data is represented inside the machine.

Worry not, The double quotes will be there when you export the data back to JSON.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have not met this problem before, I still don't understand how to return the JSON object with quotes on the key after checking the link on your answer. Any ideas?

Comment: If you use `puts({sum: 9}.to_json)` you will see that the object is formatted as JSON (instead of the source Ruby object) and will have the quotes.